# how to check serialize data is empty on submit button's click

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

my question is how to check whether the input value of the bootstrap popup model is empty or not by clicking on the button using ajax and ajax serialize method.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
        var data = $('#aget_form').serialize();
        if(data =='')
        {
        alert("error");
         }
        console.log(data);
        var formdata = new FormData();
        var img = $('#user_image')[0].files[0];
        formdata.append('image',img);
        formdata.append('data',data);
      }
}
</script>
```

Comment: _"of the popup model"_ - What "popup model"? Please edit your question to include _all_ info (including the form you're serializing).

Comment: Stuffing already serialized from data into a post parameter makes rather little sense to begin with. You should rather create your FormData object by passing the reference to the form element in as parameter, then it will take care of serializing the data for submission by itself.

Comment: popup model means bootstrap popup model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check every input by using **each** on all input fields

```
$(form).find('input').each(function(index, elem){
   if($(elem).val().length == 0){
       //this field is empty
   }
});
```